# When realm count reaches around 470, Keycloak basically becomes unstable

Tags: performance-testing, keycloak

We are having a Keycloak 4.8.1.Final deployed on a k8 cluster with two
nodes with default settings. Backend database is PostgreSQL.

We are increasing the number of realms in Keycloak to figure out if
Keycloak can support a larger number of realms; these creations are done
sequentially.

However, when the quantity of realms reach around 470, it makes keycloak
basically unusable with admin GUI not loading at all and requests taking
too long to execute.

Below is a summary of the time taken. We have not added any users into the
realms.

```
+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|  Operation   | 0 realms | 100 realms | 250 realms | 350 realms |
+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| Create realm |     1104 |       3739 |       8659 |      11535 |
| Get realm    |      128 |        961 |       3067 |       3853 |
| Get token    |      636 |       1159 |       2714 |       3197 |
| Get roles    |      127 |       1037 |       3034 |       3649 |
+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Are there any known limitations or an optimal number of realms for a
Keycloak deployment?

Already raised in [user group](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-January/017103.html) as well.

Comment: The reason for this is Keycloak load all the realm in the cache at once

Comment: Is there any news about this limitation ?

Comment: @lkamal could you try enabling the `pg_stat_statements` extension for your Postgres instance, and sharing info on the performance of DB queries, e.g. using `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements ORDER BY max_exec_time DESC`.

Comment: if my memory serves me there was a corresponding issue in Keycloak Jira and in recent or near future releases was/should be some improvements concerning multiple realms performance

Comment: @lkamal it would also be helpful to know: a) what's the CPU usage of the `keycloak` process while waiting for requests to finish? b) what's the CPU usage of the `postgres` process? c) what machine type (CPU, RAM, disk type) is the `keycloak` and `postgres` processes running on? Which of these are the bottleneck?

Comment: @runeks sorry I do not have access to that environment now. Sorry, this is 2 years old now :(. As I can recall, I was a simple developer cluster with around 2 CPU & 4/8GB memory. I am not sure about the spec of the postgres node.

Comment: That's very broad question. But very likely it is a problem with the cache configuration as it was already mentioned in the previous comment. Maybe inefficient role configuration or other issues.

Answer (score 3):

There has been some opened issues on this for quite a while:

- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-6826
- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-6535
- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-4593
- http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Keycloak-Performance-with-large-number-of-realms-td3853.html
- https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-October/008061.html

From what I recall, several sources point out that decrease of performance at about 400 realms. However, none of the issues above seem to have already been effectively tackled.

Comment: Excellent thread on the topic also https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/11074